# Swift RestKit won't post JSON in body

Tags: json, swift, core-data, restkit-0.20

I need to do a post to receive back JSON to populate my CoreData. Up to this point I was only do GETs.

No matter what combination when I view the call from Charles, nothing is in the body.

```
let storedProcedureParams =
    [
        "params": [
            [
            "name": "p_latitude",
            "param_type": "IN",
            "value": latitude
            ],
            [
            "name": "p_longitude",
            "param_type": "IN",
            "value": longitude
            ],
            [
            "name": "p_distance",
            "param_type": "IN",
            "value": distance
            ],
            [
            "name": "p_user",
            "param_type": "IN",
            "value" : user
            ],
            [
            "name": "p_appKey",
            "param_type": "IN",
            "value" : appDelegate.api_key
            ]
        ],
        "schema": [
            "id": "integer",
            "complete": "boolean"
        ],
        "wrapper": "record"
    ]

    let mapping = RKObjectMapping.requestMapping()
    mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(storedProcedureParams)

    let requestDescriptor = RKRequestDescriptor(mapping:mapping,objectClass:Store.self, rootKeyPath:nil, method:RKRequestMethod.POST)


    objectManager.addRequestDescriptor(requestDescriptor)
    objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor )
    objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON
    objectManager.postObject(storedProcedureParams, path: "_proc/StoresByDistance", parameters: nil,
                             success:{ operation, mappingResult in
                                NSLog("success")


        },
                             failure:{ operation, error in
                                NSLog("Error loading list': \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                                //return nil
        }
    );
```

Anything obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, I had to set the requestDescriptor to nil, and then use the params which sent it in the body.